Someone explain how a naked singularity is possible
I was reading this Wikipedia article about naked singularities, however I don't really understand the how a gravitational singularity can simply exist without an event horizon. Can someone explain/summarize the article for me? And what would an object like that look like to a human observer. Could such an object be the hypothesized white holes?

It isn't possible. BH singularities are arguably a glorified error of Einstein's theory.

@Mithoron: This post is about naked singularities, i.e. singularities with no event horizon. Black hole singularities do exist inside event event horizons, according to current theory.

@LeeMosher Singularities are in the maths, and what they say is that Relativity isn't as great as people think, and better theory is needed. Therefore even considering some "naked singularities" is a waste of time. If you wanna do it nonetheless, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_censorship_hypothesis for example.

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20349/5278

The answer is we do not have a firm theory for the formation of naked singularities. Physicists have identified conditions that would enable such singularities, but the conditions run afoul of limitations posed by our current theories of relativistic mechanics.
The Wikipedia article referenced in the question describes the two simplest scenarios — and the problems associated with them.

If an uncharged black hole is spinning fast enough, then the event horizon surrounding the associated ring singularity would disappear turning the proposed black hole into a naked ring singularity. But relativistic mechanics (involving the famed speed-of-light limit) appears to show that the required spin rate is beyond physically achievable conditions.

If a black hole has enough charge built into it, the electrostatic forces associated with this charge can cause the horizon to again disappear. But because the implied electrostatic energy is also additional mass in relativistic physics, the amount of charge apparently can't become large enough relative to the mass for the naked singularity to emerge.



How can a black hole be charged?

Objects giving off charged particles need not remain neutral. Even Earth actually has chatge separation between the surface and the atmosphere, so if you include only the solid planet it's charged.

so can a singularity be charged? Also for a naked singularity would the singularity need to be charged or the accretion disc or giving off enough energy through hawking radiation?
